# How to dynamically assign an object if the incoming json can change?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have classes:

```
abstract class BaseItem {
    teamName: string;
}

export class ReleaseRoadmapItem extends BaseItem {
    startDate: Date;
    goal: string;
}

export class ControlPointRoadmapItem extends  BaseItem {
    workItemLink: string;
    isClosed: boolean;
}
```

Json data may vary in different ways. Method get() return array the type of each the class BaseItem.

```
export class ApiService {

    constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) { }

    get(): Observable<BaseItem []>  {
        return this.http.get<BaseItem []>(`api/Roadmap);
    }
}
```

But the type of all objects BaseItem. How can I initialize Json objects with the desired type?

For example Json data :

```
[
  {
    "teamName":"companyName",
    "startDate": "01-01-2001",
    "goal": "goal"
  },
  {
    "teamName":"companyName",
    "workItemLink": "http://...",
    "isClosed": true
  }
]
```

I want to get the result.

```
ApiService.get().subscribe(x =>{
 let isRoadmapItem = x[0] is ReleaseRoadmapItem; // True
 let isPointRoadmapItem = x[1] is ControlPointRoadmapItem; // True
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
export type RoadMapItem = ReleaseRoadmapItem | ControlPointRoadmapItem;

get(): Observable<RoadMapItem[]>  {
        return this.http.get<RoadMapItem[]>(`api/Roadmap);
    }
```

Edit: Your example JSON data is not an array.

Comment: type of x[0] is "Object"

Comment: https://aliolicode.com/2016/04/23/type-checking-typescript/ may help you